# QGIS 3.24 - how to export points as arc or polygon

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, point

I have a GPS coordinate file that defines points (locations.)

I have a second application that is limited in that it can only show arc or polygon shapefiles. This application can't process a point file, which I know how to create.

How can I export a shapefile into an arc or polygon shp type rather than a point type?

I've considered creating small circular polygons based on the point with a radius of say 1m, but can't figure out how to do that - I am extremely new to GIS.

Comment: Check the vector-tool `buffer`.

Comment: You can't convert points to line or polygon without deciding how you're going to represent them first.

Comment: After bumbling around for an hour, I finally figured out how to add a buffer, however, I can't successfully make the buffer "small." It ends up being several hundred miles across.

Comment: Well Vince, I honestly don't know how to represent them. I'm 5 hours into QGIS in an attempt to "simply" place some dots on a map. The application that is causing me problems was never meant to support points as I've found out, which baffles me, but it is what it is. So I thought that making little polygons that look like dots would suffice, but that is turning out to be a challenge as well.

Comment: If your GPS points are in the WGS 84 geographic coordinate system, then your buffer units are degrees and hence they would be quite a bit larger than you expect.  You can use a degrees to meters (or feet) converter (or do it manually) and then use that much smaller number for your buffer polygons, or you can export your points to a new shapefile with a coordinate system (CRS dropdown) that uses meter or feet units and buffer that.  If that needs to be in WGS 84 for your second application, then export those using the WGS 84 CRS.